# Unable to use predict function

Tags: r, statistics

I am having an issue running predictions with multiple iv's. I have 3 Iv's and co efficient table from them but I am not sure what to input into the formula, the coefficients table is as follows, and i am looking to predict variables tempo slow, gender male and Stroop hard, I have currently run the code below but it comes up with error.

```
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.01868    0.45683  -0.041    0.967
temposlow    0.65266    0.54402   1.200    0.230
gendermale   1.12159    0.84118   1.333    0.182
stroophard   0.40429    0.55356   0.730    0.465

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 83.201  on 64  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 78.978  on 61  degrees of freedom
AIC: 86.978

> -0.01868 + ( 1.12159 * gendermale)
Error: object 'gendermale' not found
```

Tried this, i am expecting a value which i can turn into a percentage using the function 'plogis'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: take a look at ``predict`` function`  ``?predict.glm``